# Is (have + object) followed by 'infinitive', 'gerund' or 'past participle' in this context?

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund, past-participles

I want to know which is appropriate one to fill the gap in.

> Leslie had a very strange thing __(happen) when she was in Romania.
>
> 1. happen
> 2. happening
> 3. happened

*Oxfor Grammar* explains that I can use either *infinitive* or *gerund* to talk about experiences. However, in the other section, it also tells me that for passive, I can use *past participle*. So, in that sentence above, which one is appropriate and why? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either 1 or 2 is possible. You can speak of what happened as a completed thing (happen) or as a process that was continuing for a time (happening). The infinitive (happen) is more likely.

*Happen* is intransitive, so it can't be made passive, and *happened* doesn't fit there.

Comment: You think "Leslie had a very strange thing happening when she was in Romania" is even possible?  It sounds very wrong to me (Northeast US native speaker).

Comment: I think it's possible. "Leslie had a very strange thing happening when she was in Romania. Every night when she went to bed, she would have dreams about Dracula. When she crossed to Bulgaria, the dreams disappeared."